# Strange compiler behaviour with generic lambda in C++14

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

I recently came across an interesting quirk of GCC, when using generic lambdas (C++14 feature that allows usage of `auto` as lambda parameter). It seems that using auto instead of type, somehow affects how "this" pointer is captured. I reproduced problem in following example:

```
#include <cstdio>

class A { private:
    void method(int i) {
        printf("Method Call %d",i);
    }

public:
    void publicMethod() {
        auto lambda = [&] (const int k) { //problematic line
            method(k);                    //problematic line
        };
        lambda(42);
    } };

int main() {
    A a;
    a.publicMethod();
    return 0; }
```

Code above works. When I change "problematic lines" to:

```
        auto lambda = [&] (const auto k) { //problematic line
            method(k);                     //problematic line
```

It's not compiling anymore, however adding "this" pointer:

```
        auto lambda = [&] (const auto k) { //problematic line
            this->method(k);               //problematic line
```

Resolves the issue. My question is: Is there any rational reason for such behaviour? Or is it GCC's irrational quirk (and maybe should be reported)?

Here is output from compiler on case with usage of `auto` without `this`

```
test.cpp: In lambda function:
test.cpp:12:13: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
             method(k);
             ^
0x848ecc crash_signal
    ../../src/gcc/toplev.c:383
0xea28e5 size_binop_loc(unsigned int, tree_code, tree_node*, tree_node*)
    ../../src/gcc/fold-const.c:1768
0xee86d7 gimplify_compound_lval
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:2039
0xee86d7 gimplify_expr(tree_node**, gimple_statement_base**, gimple_statement_base**, bool (*)(tree_node*), int)
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:8052
0xeeb639 gimplify_arg(tree_node**, gimple_statement_base**, unsigned int)
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:2271
0xeeb639 gimplify_call_expr
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:2477
0xee89f2 gimplify_expr(tree_node**, gimple_statement_base**, gimple_statement_base**, bool (*)(tree_node*), int)
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:8071
0xee8da7 gimplify_stmt(tree_node**, gimple_statement_base**)
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:5519
0xee8da7 gimplify_cleanup_point_expr
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:5295
0xee8da7 gimplify_expr(tree_node**, gimple_statement_base**, gimple_statement_base**, bool (*)(tree_node*), int)
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:8463
0xee7ace gimplify_stmt(tree_node**, gimple_statement_base**)
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:5519
0xee94db gimplify_bind_expr
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:1136
0xee94db gimplify_expr(tree_node**, gimple_statement_base**, gimple_statement_base**, bool (*)(tree_node*), int)
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:8297
0xee757f gimplify_stmt(tree_node**, gimple_statement_base**)
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:5519
0xee757f gimplify_body(tree_node*, bool)
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:9234
0xee72fd gimplify_function_tree(tree_node*)
    ../../src/gcc/gimplify.c:9388
0xe195e0 cgraph_node::analyze()
    ../../src/gcc/cgraphunit.c:634
0xe195e0 analyze_functions
    ../../src/gcc/cgraphunit.c:1024
0x127d1ab symbol_table::finalize_compilation_unit()
    ../../src/gcc/cgraphunit.c:2453
0xd37db5 cp_write_global_declarations()
    ../../src/gcc/cp/decl2.c:4843
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
```

Compiled with GCC 5.3.1

Comment: `internal compiler error` That's a compiler bug.

Comment: On Clang it [works as indented](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/lTOF7QxfICP6sW0l).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for comments. Indeed, it is GCC bug - my colleague just reported it to GCC support:

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69977